# PSQL query is working in POSTGRES but gives error in JDBCTemplate

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, psql, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have my PSQL query running fine in POSTGRES
[image]

However when I run the same query in JDBCTemplate I get an error.

```
public List<RentalDto> selectRentalsByDistance(Double lon, Double lat) {
        var sql = """                
                SELECT *
                FROM (
                SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos(radians(-33.859200) ) * cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians(longitude) - radians(151.092804) )
                + sin( radians(-33.859200) ) * sin( radians(latitude) )) ) AS distance
                FROM rental
                ) AS subquery
                WHERE distance < 25
                ORDER BY distance
                LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
                """;
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rentalDtoRowMapper, lon, lat);
}
```

The error is

```
nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.] with root cause
```

Comment: Try fully qualifying the table name in your jdbc template. Use the schema name plus the table name and see if that makes a difference. 

Also your first screenshot is not psql. Psql is a command line. You are using a gui client that likely has different connection information than your other code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my rentalDtoRowMapper. The rentalDtoRowMapper class was using the toInstant() method on SQL Date data which caused a Null Pointer Exception causing the issue. I had to convert the SQL Date to Java Util Date before using the toInstant() method.